# How do I select from a column that might be boolean or the string '1'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas dataframe that I grab from a database, so I don't have much control over the format. For reasons that defy explanation, in some cases, the query returns True/False, in others, it returns 1/NULL. This goes into a csv, which is then later read into the dataframe.

If the column is True/False, they're read correctly, and I can say:

```
DF = DF[DF['column']]
```

to only get the rows where the column has True. It's great.

However, when the data is 1/Null, the 1 is a string, so everything gets messed up.

I'd LIKE to do:

```
DF = DF[ DF['column'] or DF['column'] == '1']
```

However, that doesn't work.

ALternatively, if there was a way to easily check if I have '1'/'' and if so, convert the column into True/False, that would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy, because number `1` is equal `True`. So I first convert values to `string` and then check string `1` by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'column':[True, True, 1,  1, 1]})
print DF

  column
0   True
1   True
2      1
3      1
4      1

print DF[DF['column'].astype(str).str.contains('1')]

  column
2      1
3      1
4      1
```

Or use old `Ayhan` solution:

```
print  DF[DF['column'].astype(str) == '1' ]

  column
2      1
3      1
4      1
```

EDIT:

If you need check `True` or number `1`:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'column':[True, True, 1,  1, 1, False, 2]})
print DF
  column
0   True
1   True
2      1
3      1
4      1
5  False
6      2

print DF[DF['column'] == 1]
  column
0   True
1   True
2      1
3      1
4      1

print DF[DF['column'] == True]
  column
0   True
1   True
2      1
3      1
4      1
```

It works, because `True` is equal `1` in comparing.

Comment: The | doesn't work. I tried:

DF = [DF['column'] | DF['column'] == '1']

But that gave an error

Comment: I get TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: What is `print type(df.at[0, 'column'])` ?

Comment: Sometimes it's numpy.bool. Othertimes it's numpy.int64 Interesting, I thought it was a string... but that doesn't actually help it seems.

Comment: And I don't need to worry about null, it's basically, I want everything which has either True, or 1 in that column.

Comment: Right, but in this case I want all 5 rows

Comment: Ok, possible values are true, 1 and some other?

Comment: AH, all I needed was the ==1 I instictually remove "== 1" because it's always redundant. .... Except when it isn't. *sigh*

Comment: Phuuu, first I think you need distinguish `1` and `True` and I cant do it long time. Now I get it. Thank you for accepting and upvoting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are pulling from a database where you know that you will have these situations, why not just do a blanket replace?

```
In [70]:  df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': ['hello',True,''], "b": 

[1,'bar',None]}, index=['row1','row2', 'row3'])

In [71]:  df.replace(to_replace={1:True,'1':True,'':False,None:False})
Out[71]:
          a      b
row1  hello   True
row2   True    bar
row3  False  False

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
          a     b
row1  hello     1
row2   True   bar
row3         None

In [73]:
```

With this approach you can have a clean mapping dictionary of values that you'd like to replace.

This can also be done at the column level, if there are only specific columns it would be used on:

```
In [6]: df.a.replace({np.bool(1):True, np.bool(0):False, 1:True,'1':True,'':False,None:False}, inplace=True)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
               a      b
row1       hello      1
row2        True    bar
row3       False   None
npboolrow   True  False
```

Comment: I get:     DF['column'].replace({1:True, '1':True, '':False, None: False}, inplace=True)
    raise TypeError("Cannot compare types %r and %r" % tuple(type_names))
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=bool)' and 'str'

Comment: you should change the mapping dict to: {np.bool(1)}.  Answer edited to something that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, just enclose each rule in parenthesis and use | for the logical OR.

```
In [1]: DF = pd.DataFrame({'column':[True, True, 1,  '1', 1, False, 2]})

In [2]: DF[(DF['column'] == True) | (DF['column'] == 1)]
Out[2]:
  column
0   True
1   True
2      1
4      1
```

You can add a third rule in the same way

```
In [3]: DF[(DF['column'] == True) | (DF['column'] == 1) | (DF['column'] == '1')]
Out[3]:
  column
0   True
1   True
2      1
3      1
4      1
```